# I wonder if its possible to store the image upload to server store outside jar, and how to find the direction

Tags: linux, spring-boot, web, jar, image-uploading

I created a spring-boot web project and uploaded it to server already(centOS7).
currently the img upload to jar file on server is stored inside the static package in jar file
this makes the jar file very large and hard to edit.
can some one give me a idea to store the img somewhere else on server and how to find the position of picture out of jar inside html.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to decide, in which directory you are going to store your files and create it: 
`mkdir /path/to/your/dir`

Then assign a newly created directory to your application user:`chown <your user>:<users group> /path/to/your/dir`

Then, don't forget to give read/write permissions for the user, under which you run your app - to the already created directory. 
`chmod 600 /path/to/your/dir` - this will allow your app to only read/write to the directory and prevent the execution of files within it (for security reasons).

Then just replace the path you already have - with the new one (to the newly created directory).

Please, be aware that there is a lot of **security** stuff to consider when you're going to store files on your server.

By the way, please consider reading about different storage options like [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and [Ceph](https://ceph.com/).

Please, take into account - that if you're going to store your files on your server - then you should take care about them (for example: keep eyes on space, make sure you have mirroring across discs and so on so forth). With AWS S3, for example, you don't need to care about all of that stuff and it's very cheap.

Comment: Thank you for replying.And can you give a bit more detail about how to use google cloud storage link to spring-boot. the official tutorial is not that clear.

Comment: @TaoLin, I think you have to try it first and then come back with concrete questions. The programmer should be OK with reading the documentation and implementing the logic, described there. Especially if this documentation is written by Google.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try that

Comment: sadly i still can't upload to google cloud storage.could you please see my new question?